# JavaScript indexOf giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a code which requires me to get index of a string in an array. I am using JavaScript indexOf function to achieve this. Problem here is that I am able to get the index of numbers which are coded as string but not able to get the index for strings.

```
var codes = ["1", "2", "‍2A", "‍2B", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "21", "22", 
            "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33",
            "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44",
            "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55",
            "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", 
            "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77",
            "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88",
            "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95"];
console.log(codes.indexOf("2A"));
```

The response I am receiving in the console is -1 instead of 2 since "2A" is lying at 2nd position.

Comment: Your code is working here. I believe that the typo was a missing comma

Comment: When I paste your code into a jsFiddle, I see non-printing characters show up in red. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mmdxn0vv/. Fix that and you're fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected result from String.indexOf function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195583/unexpected-result-from-string-indexof-function)

Comment: I tested the code again and saw no typo in here. However, I was getting the array of strings from some tools which was giving some invisible invalid character in front of 2A and 2B which is caught by @j08691 . Thanks to all of you to help me find out the reason why code was not working.

Answer (score 11):

The character is not `2A`, it contains a non-printing character symbol [*Zero Width Joiner*](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8205) at the beginning of the string.

This can be verified from

```
console.log("‍2A".charCodeAt(0)); // > 8205 // Note that the string is copied from the array `codes`
```

This is making the string invalid.

No wonder why `indexOf` is not giving correct index.

Answer (score 3):

Your codes array has error. indexOf is working fine. See what happen when I paste codes array in jsfiddle (attach image)

[image: Problem with image]